# Emacs lisp - correct way to wrap function

Tags: emacs

Hi I need to wrap a function, what is the best practice to achieve this? Here's currently my working implmentation:

```
(defun my-counsel-projectile-find-file (&optional arg)
  "Jump to a project's file using completion.

Wraps `counsel-projectile-find-file' to be compatible with `puspose-mode'"
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((purpose--active-p nil))
    (counsel-projectile-find-file arg))
  )
```

In this case I'm wrapping the `counsel-projectile-find-file` function.

Comment: Wrap for what purpose? There are lots of ways to wrap a function call, and lots of uses for such wrapping. What you show here is fine. But the question is a bit too general/unclear. If you are just asking whether your code is a good way to accomplish what it does then the answer is yes - it's fine.